# Why embed repo command in a bash script?

Tags: python, android, bash

I was investigating repo (from Android project) source code.
It start with the following :

```
#!/bin/sh
magic='--calling-python-from-/bin/sh--'
"""exec" python -E "$0" "$@" """#$magic"
```

If I understand it well, it means that the script is recalling itself with python.
So there is my question, why do not directly use python.

For example I usually use something like :

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
```

I think there is a valuable reason, but I can't figure it out.

Thanks

Comment: You might want to ask the people maintain that repo. The lack of replies suggests there's no obvious reason.

Answer (score 4):

Answer from the repo people: [Purpose of embedding Repo python code into bash script](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!searchin/repo-discuss/python/repo-discuss/kGfa8SQRDyg/44saEe_Fi3kJ)

Comment: While this explains **what** it does and **how** it works (both interesting), it does not explain why the simpler `env` trick isn't used.

Comment: A normal `env` shebang won't pass the `-E` flag properly on many systems (Linux systems, for one). See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shebang_%28Unix%29#Portability

Answer (score 3):

Google developer Shawn Pearce gives the reason in [this discussion](http://groups.google.com/group/repo-discuss/browse_thread/thread/9067daf124110f28):

> We need to pass the -E flag, but env on some platforms wasn't taking 
>   it. So I cooked up this work around. It mostly had to do with our 
>   internal desktops at Google; they have a lot of PYTHON environment 
>   flags that we didn't want to inherit into the repo process (because 
>   they are there for normal Google engineers, not Android Google 
>   engineers), and at least at the time env on either Mac OS or Linux (I 
>   can't remember which) was rejecting a shbang line of "#!/usr/bin/env 
>   python -E".

Answer (score 0):

Perl and Ruby have a '-x' command-line switch, used to do something like setting up shell environment variables before starting the interpeter itself -- mixing shell commands and perl/ruby in the same file:

```
#!/bin/sh
export PERL5LIB=/some/perl/lib/path:$PERL5LIB
export FOO=1

exec perl -x $0 $@

# ^^^^ ---- shell commands above this line ---- ^^^^
#!perl
# vvvv ---- perl script below this line ---- vvvv
use strict;

print "Hello world\n":
```

The 'magic' bit in repo is the author's solution to this problem -- but less flexible and far more obtuse. It's sadly a missing feature in python.